# Stylus Nib Gradients

Tags: html, css, nib, stylus, linear-gradients

I'm hoping someone here will know the answer to this problem as its driving me a bit mental right now.

The problem is that my gradients will only work horizontally but not vertically. When I try to make it go from top to bottom on the page, it repeats in stripes. See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/341r2.png) 
I have used Chromium, Chrome and Firefox on this and all of them show the same thing.

I'm using NPM, Gulp and Stylus which all work fine. I tried using Kouto-Swiss but ran into this gradient issue so I tried Nib instead, had the same issues. I think I might be missing something obvious but I can't see it. This little project is actually for me to play around with Flexbox but this gradient problem needs fixing.

Here's the code:
[All Files In This Bin](http://pastebin.com/u/RawrBear)

Excuse the sloppiness, its a testing ground :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height:100%` to html and body rules in your CSS.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: And that works perfectly! Thanks for the help :)
I used height 100% on the body before but not the html too, using both was the fix!

I tried to up vote your answer but I don't have enough rep yet :(

Comment: No problem. I ran into this a few months ago.